# Use Vim to edit Simulink blocks

Tags: matlab, vim, simulink

When I click on a function block in Simulink, it's Matlab code is opened in Matlab editor. I don't like it. I'd rather use Vim.

I tried changing editor in Matlab Preferences (*Home->Environment->Preferences-> Editor/Debuger*). I switched editor from "MATLAB Editor" to *C:\Program Files(x86)\Vim\vim80\vim.exe*.

But that makes vim open only when I type "edit" command in command line.

Using Matlab R2014b under Windows 7.